# Rails - send reservation request with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a car and user model. User has many cars and car belongs to user model. In the car model, I have columns named `renter_status` & `owner_status` with default value to "Pending". During the process either of the user can cancel the request.

Lets say, John has a car with id = 1 and Jane would like to send a reservation request to John between two dates. When Jane sends a reservation request, the request is sent to owner if owner approves, then owner_request becomes "Approved". Then Jane can see that the request has been approved and if Jane cancels, then renter_request becomes "Cancelled".

I think there must be a way of doing this better with rails associations. I have two user but when they read & write to same model, I have to check renter_status and owner_status all time.

Lets say, John wanted to delete the request and does not want to see it in index action. When he does, the column owner_status becomes "Deleted", but his request can be seen as Jane is not deleted yet.

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I think you have to use has_many through associations http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association  to save all your requests

Answer (score 0):

I think i'm kinda lost. So you have 2 models , `Car` and `User` and the associations are like this :
Car

```
belongs_to :user
```

User

```
has_many :cars
```

I would make a third model, `Requests` because one `Car` should have more than one 'Request' , let's say, in one month. But if you really want to do this , you should not let John delete the request but to cancel it.
You can do this kind of behavior adding a control in the view you are editing the request with , for example, a submit button that will call an action in your controller that will change the value to "rejected".
After this you can index the not rejected requests like this:

Rails 4

```
@requests_not_rejected = Car.where.not(renter_status: 'Rejected')
```

Rails 3

```
@requests_not_rejected = Car.where(Car.arel_table[:renter_status].not_eq(me))
```

When you are recording these kind of actions, normally you wouldn't delete them.